# I am not able to find XACML editing entry in WSO2 identity server

Tags: wso2

The WSO2 identity server was successfully started but after logging in, I can only see My Identity tab in the home page, no entitle page and any other pages are presented, why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this documentation link

https://docs.wso2.org/display/IS460/Creating+an+XACML+Policy

Also here are some tutorials that you can follow..

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2010/10/using-xacml-fine-grained-authorization-wso2-platform/

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/11/fine-grained-xacml-authoriation-with-pip-points/

Answer (score 0):

What is the Identity Server Version you are using? Is it the latest IS 5.0.0? If you have proper admin privilages, you should be able to see the Entitlement related pages under Home    > Entitlement   > PAP   > Policy Administration